# linux + single user mode and set network

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

I have linux redhat machine version 6.5

I reboot machine and work as single user mode ,

then I set the network on eth0 with default gw address

```
/etc/sysconfig/network-script/ifcfg-eth0
```

but from some reason dg address not appears from **netstat -rn** after service network restart

my question - can we set default gw address and start network when we in single user mode ?

Comment: 1) why after `service network restart`? Was it started at all?
2) you can debug `systemctl` with `journalctl` 
3) after you found the exact problem, ask about the corresponding instruments. Was it because of `rfkill`, bridges or whatsoever.

Comment: If the problem is with default gateway address, then find how to set that. It has nothing to do with single user mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single-user mode by definition does not implement networking at startup.  To put it in sysV runlevel terms, you want runlevel 2 (local multi-user with networking).  You can switch to this with `telinit 2`.

The standard runlevel definitions are:

- 0 - Halt the system
- 1 - Single-user mode
- 2 - Multi-user with networking, but no network services (e. g. NFS)
- 3 - Multi-user with networking and services
- 4 - Undefined
- 5 - Multi-user with networking, services, and GUI (e. g. Xorg)
- 6 - Reboot the system.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Of course, by default `runlevel 1` doesn't allow networking, but one can start networking from `runlevel 1` using `systemctl network start`. There is no need to change `runlevel` in order to start only network.

Comment: I have modified my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Bringing network up in single user mode

```
ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x up


route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.x


ip route list
```

Ping IP address from outside and check whether it is pinging or not.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Yes it is possible to start in single user mode, and then add networking.

The best way to do depends on your machine.

As per Yaroslav Nikitenko's comment, it can be as simple as:

```
systemctl network start
```

Or, as per Venkatesh's answer, you can probably give the commands directly:

```
ifconfig eth0 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x up
route add default gw xxx.xxx.xxx.x
...
```

It isn't necessary to go to runlevel 2. If you do, it will probably work, but it isn't guaranteed. It just depends on how runlevel 2 is defined on your machine.