# Recover ssh connexion after init 1

Tags: ssh, remote, init

After `init 1`, the ssh connexion on a remote server was interrupted with the following error

> packet_write_wait: Connection to UNKNOWN port 0: Broken pipe

Now, even root cannot connect

```
$ ssh root@remoteserver
ssh: connect to host remoteserver port 22: Connection refused
```

Is there any way to recover a ssh connexion?

Comment: Probably not - [runlevel 1 doesn't provide networking](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276279/linux-single-user-mode-and-set-network/276280#276280).  Which unix/linux distribution are you using?

Comment: It is Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to runlevel 1 kills all processes (except the top-level `init`/upstart command itself), including the SSH daemon.

From http://www.debianadmin.com/debian-and-ubuntu-linux-run-levels.html:

> Run Level 1 is known as ‘single user' mode. A more apt description would be ‘rescue', or ‘trouble-shooting' mode. In run level 1, no daemons (services) are started. Hopefully single user mode will allow you to fix whatever made the transition to rescue mode necessary.

The easiest way to get `sshd` running is to switch to a runlevel that starts it by default.  In Ubuntu, that's any of 2, 3, 4 and 5.

If you can't access the single-user shell to enter the `init` or `telinit` command, eg. because you were connected remotely, or it's [hidden by the splash screen](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/705150), then you're out of luck.  The only option left is to reboot.